# Can a Subscriber send text (JSON) data back to the Publisher

Tags: opentok, tokbox

When they connect.

I tried sending a TokBox Signal from the publisher, but so far the message only get delivered to the publisher who originated it  (I have not tried from the subscriber)

My operation mode is:
- Publisher starts presenting
- Subscribers join and watch publisher
- Publisher can then start a two way session with a subscriber

For that, i need to map the streams back to the devices, I could use database updates, but is messaging is more direct (hence the look at signals).

Answer (score 2):

To map streams to devices the best way is to include some connection data when you generate the tokens for each user:
https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/create-token/

That way when you receive a stream you can check it's connection data like:
`stream.connection.data` and wee the user/device it belongs to.

For example you could add as connection data `username=lionel` so that everybody can figure out later what streams belongs to that user.

Comment: Yes, I have been doing this for a while on the android client, whereas the connection.data has the json, when queried by the subscriber, the publisher is not getting the data that is being sent over the signal api (i see this data going right back to the subscriber - but it does not make it to the publsiher)

Answer (score 0):

RTM: https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/signaling/js/#send_signal_to_client

```
private Connection connection;

private SessionListener sessionListener = new SessionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Session session) {
        connection = session.getConnection();
    }
    ....
}
```

that should do the trick for sendSignal(..,..,connection);